# how to change default date format when creating table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

how to change default date format when creating table in MYSQL

Comment: Do you mean the format itself (i.e.: YYYY-MM-DD, etc.) or the default value?

Answer (score 7):

You can't change the default **format** for a date during the table definition stage. (It must always obey the DATETIME, DATE or TIMESTAMP formats.) As the manual puts it:

> Although MySQL tries to interpret
>   values in several formats, dates
>   always must be given in year-month-day
>   order (for example, '98-09-04'),
>   rather than in the month-day-year or
>   day-month-year orders commonly used
>   elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98',
>   '04-09-98').

See the [date and time reference docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html) for more info.

As such, you'll have to use the [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function at the point of output to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) functions to communicate with MySQL using different date formats.

Example using `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15-Dec-09 1:00:00 PM', '%d-%b-%y %h:%i:%S %p') AS date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2009-12-15 13:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

Example using `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-12-15 13:00:00', '%d-%b-%y %h:%i:%S %p') AS date;
+-----------------------+
| date                  |
+-----------------------+
| 15-Dec-09 01:00:00 PM |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```