# what is the format with which mysql stores date and time?

Tags: php, mysql

While creating a table, I defined one column of `DATE` type and one of `TIME` type. As I insert the values using a `php script` like :

```
date--> 2013-11-11
time--> 12:12:12
```

and when I query the sql browser I see those values in exactly the same manner. But I am unaware of the format with which it stores the `date` and `time`. Like `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-dd-mm`.

Is there any way I change it ?

Comment: I think your safest solution to avoid this problem entirely is to create three fields: One that contains a timestamp, and the other two that extract the date and time from the timestamp. You get to choose the format yourself, and in coding, you just need to point to the timestamp to avoid any questions.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html

Comment: Using largest parameter first and smallest last YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss allows mysql to string compare the values. Try creating files on you PC using dates as names. If you use dd-mm-yyyy all 1st will be at the top. You shouldnt care about the storage format, it the display format you should be concerned with. Avoid timestamps, as they are likely to cause headaches, when moving servers or upgrading servers with different epoch. If you want to __use__ timestamps strtotime(); on mysql will give it to you correctly

Answer (score 0):

The datetime is in Y-m-d H:i:s format, or year month day and hour minute second. If you only use a part, the format stays the same.

If you want to change the format there are many ways. The easiest would be to do something like `return date("Y-d-m H:i:s", strtotime($mysqldatetime));` (will turn it to dutch date);

Keep in mind that you are using two seperate columns, one for time and one for the date. If you use only one column the missing values are filled with default values (time would be `00:00:00` and date would be `1970-01-01`

Answer (score 0):

Dates and times are stored in MySQL in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" and "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" which is not necessarily the format you want to display in your web page or application. There are two methods to reformat the date and time into the desired format. One is to do it in the SQL query in MySQL calling the DATE_FORMAT() function and the other is to do it with the programming language retrieving the data from the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

For second question: you can't change default DATE format for the storage, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350465/how-to-change-default-date-format-when-creating-table-in-mysql) also

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format

I do not believe this can be changed. But you do not care. You can extract dates and times in the format of your liking with the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and the [`TIME_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the internal storage of Date columns, you can check [Date and Time Data Type Representation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html), but I think you want to select date in different format; which other guys already answered about it.

It is stored in 3 bytes, and it is always YYYY-MM-DD.