# Is there a way to change the default date input format

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have a source of data from where I extract some fields, among the fields there are some *date* fields and the source sends their values like this

```
#DD/MM/YYYY#
```

almost all the fields can be sent into the query with no modificaction, except this of course.

I have written a program the gets the data from an internet connection and sends it to the MySQL server and it's sending everything as it should, I am sure because I enabled general logging in the MySQL server and I can see all the queries are correct, except the ones with date fields.

I would like to avoid parsing the fields this way because it's a lot of work since it's all written in c, but if there is no way to do it, I understand and would accept that as an answer of course.

As an example suppose we had the following

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('#12/10/2015#', ... OTHER_VALUES ..., '#11/10/2015#');
```

in this case I send the whole thing as a query using `mysql_query()` from `libmysqlclient`.

In other cases I can split the parts of the message in something that is like an instruction and the parameters, something like this

```
iab A,B,C,#12/10/2015#,X,Y,#11/10/2015#
```

which could mean `INSERT INTO table_a_something_b_whatever VALUES`, and in this situation of course, I capture all the parameters and send a single query with a list of `VALUES` in it. Also in this situation, it's rather simple because I can handle the date like this

```c
char date[] = "#11/10/2015#";
int day;
int month;
int year;
if (sscanf(date, "#%d/%d/%d#", &day, &month, &year) == 3)
{
     /* it's fine, build a sane YYYY-MM-DD */
}
```

So the question is:

- How can I tell the MySQL server in what format the date fields are?

*Clarification to*: [Comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191365/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-date-input-format#comment54188660_33191365)

Not necessarily `INSERT`, it's more complex than that. They are sometimes queries with all their parameters in it, sometimes they are just the parameters and I have to build the query. It's a huge mess but I can't do anything about it because it's a paid database and I must use it for the time being.

The real problem is when the query comes from the source and has to be sent as it is, because then there can be many occurrences. When I split the parameters one by one there is no real problem because parsing the above date format and generating the appropriate value of MySQL is quite simple.

Comment: _“and sends it to the MySQL server”_ – and that means what, exactly? Are you creating simple INSERT statements that you send to the database? If you can change those, you can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to parse that format within the queries already. Otherwise, you might want to use a simple text field to insert the data into first, and then run an UPDATE query afterwards that uses the aforementioned function to transfer the value to a real date column.

Comment: @CBroe I added some clarification.

Comment: you cant do that. unless your column is a varchar (and you dont want to do that) format the date before you send to your server to be the correct date format. [heres a helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350465/how-to-change-default-date-format-when-creating-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Thing I could imagine at the Moment would be to Change your Column-Type from DateTime to varchar and use a `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger to fix "wrong" Dates.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT on myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.myDate regexp '#[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+#') THEN
    SET NEW.myDate = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.myDate,'#%d/%m/%Y#');
  END IF;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

If you are just Need to run the Import in question once, use the Trigger to generate a "proper" dateTimeColumn out of the inserts - and drop the varchar-column afterwards:

('myDate' := varchar column to be dropped afterwards;`'myRealDate' := DateTime Column to Keep afterwards)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER t1 BEFORE INSERT on myTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.myDate regexp '#[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+#') THEN
    SET NEW.myRealDate = STR_TO_DATE(NEW.myDate,'#%d/%m/%Y#');
  else 
    #assume a valid date representation
    SET NEW.myRealDate = NEW.myDate;
  END IF;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately you cannot use a Trigger to work on the datetime-column itself, because mysql will already mess up the `NEW.myDate`-Column.

Comment: why recommend storing dates as a varchar? that just opens a huge can of no-no. order by wont work without parsing on every "date" just all around a really bad idea

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm not recommending, i'm outlining an Option. And ordering on "DateTimeStrings such as 2015-05-02 18:16:25" will work in a native way, as well as comparissions like "> <". And if it's just - read the second part - a one time Import, there is no Problem in doing this. he'll end up with datetime-columns afterwards.

Comment: with your trigger you dont need to change the type though. if its formatting it to be `2015-05-02 18:16:25` then the type doesn't need to change. if its not in that format then the ordering and comparisons wouldn't work

Comment: @JohnRuddell The Point is: MySQL won't pass `#12/10/2015#` as `NEW.myDate`, because it's already failing Prior, if that's a datetime column. Only if `myDate` is a varchar, you'll get the raw-data of the insert.

Comment: @JohnRuddell the main problem with this is that it doesn't make sense from the start, if they intend to save the data in a database they designed why to send the date in that format? Even if they have a reason internal to their application or whatever use they give to the database, THEY should format it and not their costumers, and also the unnecessary not quite well specified convetion to send the data, the savings in space aren't worth it because it's compressed by apache anyway. It could be JSON and it would be so easy to do whatever you want with the data. But what can I do?

Comment: Oh and I sometimes wonder how these guys become paid professional programmers, the database costs a lot of money.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in MySQL:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('#08/10/2015#','#%d/%m%Y#');
```

Use this as part of your `INSERT` process:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (yourdatecolumn) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('#08/10/2015#','#%d/%m%Y#'));
```

Comment: This is really what I want, but I can't use it. Thank you very much, it's my fault I will clarify that in my question.